# When I try to open MAMP in windows it throws error "install .Net core"

Tags: mysql, .net-core, mamp

After installing MAMP in windows, when I open it, it throws the below error.

"To run this application, you must install .Net core. Would you like to download it now."

[error-capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmBdJ.jpg)

As advised, I tried installing .Net core 3.1 but still the same error keeps popping up when open MAMP. Please share your thoughts on this.

Comment: [Download](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/runtime-desktop-3.1.26-windows-x86-installer) this setup file install and try again

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me. You have to download the Run Desktop Apps x86 version, even if your system is x64.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Same error occurred.
So I installed older version(4.2.0) then it works.

I realized when I install new version(5.0.4), it doesn't install other runtime software. I think it is the root cause.

Try older version from here.
https://www.mamp.info/en/downloads/older-versions/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Install .net library here at Microsoft [Download .NET](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download)
please also install .NET Framework 4.0 or higher, take a look at the manual here at [manual](https://documentation.mamp.info/en/MAMP-PRO-Windows/Installation/)
[.Net download](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet)

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED] MAMP error - “To Run This Application, You Must Install .NET Core”

This worked for me. You have to download and install ".NET Core 3.1 Desktop Runtime (v3.1.26) - Windows x86" version, even if your system is x64.

My MAMP version is - (MAMP & MAMP Pro 5.0.5 - windows 10+) - https://www.mamp.info/en/downloads/

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/runtime-desktop-3.1.26-windows-x86-installer